# Developing for Desktop platforms of Linux, Mac & Windows

Tags: cross-platform, c#

I find a lot of information on developing cross-platform for mobile platforms, but not for the desktop.

Using C#, I want to create three flavours of a DESKTOP based application. All will share the core application shared code, but the Ui I want to make more platform specific, as well as the packaging...

- .deb for Linux
- .dmg for Mac
- .exe for Win

The latter one isn't a problem ofcourse, but I can't find anything on compiling to .app or .deb on Xamarin/Mono resources. Has anyone some ideas?

Thanks
Yves

Comment: This is a good question - I'm also developing a C# application and was wondering about cross-platform GUI development

Comment: I agree it's a good question. But unfortunately not for SR. We are recommending *software* here – not howtos, documentations, and courses in development. Sorry, Yves, but this simply doesn't fit here.

Comment: @Izzy - well I got recommended to post it here by the "stackoverflow" people.. where I posted it first. So now I don't know where to post this.

Comment: Ps, I will also try to get in touch with a Xamarin community representative to see what options there are. If I have more, i'll post it here.

Comment: Yves, some "people" just see the "Recommendation" in the name of this site, but never have checked what the rules are here. We have the same issue over and Android.SE, where people come with development questions "on recommendation" from some other stack (dev stuff is OT on ASE). Sorry, but I don't know a good place for that either; I'm not a dev, and I don't want to recommend a "place by name" without knowing whether it fits. As for SE sites, it's always a good idea to check the "/help/on-topic" URL first (see e.g. our [help/on-topic]) to see if it fits.